# Jmeter on running test plan log out issue

Tags: jmeter

I'm testing log in/out functionality in my application. On log in, I'm inserting a database entry, as well as for log out.

My test setup with JMeter:

1. Recording a Test Plan using WorkBench -> Add -> Non - Test Elements
   -> HTTP(s) Test Script Recorder. [Login/Logout]
2. Run the Test Plan.

On running the test plan, the user log in entry was  inserted into the database, but on log out, the user entry was not deleted from the database.

Can someone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using any cookies/Security headers for session management in ur application?

Comment: Regarding application.I don't have knowledge what they using. Database values will be SlotId : 3837245D-B11C-4644-955C-82985CE26B75 SessionId : njxymqb3mijm223t4mvvqaf5 CreatedOn : 2014-06-09 12:12:46.923 and UserMapId : 38. UserMapId value was the login user value.

Comment: You can try to use fiddler proxy tool (only 1 Mb in size)  to check  what the exact Headers,Cookies & Form data are passing while logout call is initiated. Then create http/https sampler based on that.

Comment: how to enable/copnfigure fiddler proxy tool in jmeter. Can you share me a link on fiddler proxy tool ?

Comment: Fiddler proxy is different tool. Not  a plugin to Jmeter. Plz refer http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: install Fiddler:right-hand side under Inspectors->Headers(for Logout url)->RequestToken=5llbdzgcll0mkn0xggly3k1m->undercookier->RequestToken=5llbdzgcll0mkn0xggly3k1m. Apart for this info what you need to know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55356/discussion-between-jacksantho-and-nithin-cv-poyyil).

Answer (score 1):

Add Config Element -> HTTP Cookie Manager
It should work

Comment: using HTTP Cookie Manager. Recording Controller -> Add -> Config Element -> HTTP Cookie Manager. Still I was facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Open J Meter via command prompt. 
Click on File, click on Template, disable the "User defined variables", "HTTP default requests".

- List item